# Using "grow" as a linking verb to imply a gradual process: "I recently grew the feeling that ... "

Tags: sentence-construction, usage

I wanted to say I've come to this conclusion that I wasn't good enough. I wrote:

> I grew the feeling that I haven't been good enough.

I want to know if it's fine to use "grow" as the linking verb meaning to gradually reach to a certain conclusion which mostly stems from emotion as opposed to conclusion drawn through intellectual investigations or logical pondering.

According to the dictionary, I think that's correct, but the google result for "grew the feeling that" is not promising or decisive.

Comment: How about this: **I have this growing feeling that I haven't been good enough.**

Comment: @CookieMonster I think there is some difference between "I grew" and "I have". Am I wrong? I mean the tense difference.

Comment: Yes. There is a difference in tenses between them, but how is that important?

Comment: @CookieMonster I mean "I grew: should mean it's a while that I reached to this  conclusion and I am expressing now.

Comment: @Cardinal You could also say "I have had this growing feeling for a while now that I haven't been good enough."

Comment: @Cardinal If you've already reached your conclusion, you should say, "I've come to the conclusion". As laid out in my answer, "to grow to V" is underscoring a gradual change in your attitude, not something that is already an end result.

Comment: @tenebris I see, but I don't think "I've come to" and "I grew" have the same spice. Also, I am not sure about your definition of "to grow".

Comment: @Neil That sounds cool.

Comment: @Cardinal it's not my definition. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/grow): "to have or form an opinion, attitude, etc., after time passes — followed by to + verb"

Comment: @tenebris2020 "But amid the roar of the new economy, he grew impatient and gradually dumped his blue chips"

Comment: @Cardinal First, impatience is an attitude. An attitude is different from a thought in that it describes more "how you are". Second, it doesn't say that "he grew an impatience" (which would be analogous to your "grew the feeling").

Comment: @Cardinal In Merriam-Webster, this case of "grew impatient" comes right before the one that is used with the verb: "always followed by an adjective, [linking verb] : become" with examples like "He had grown tired of..." and "He suddenly grew pale". Neither of this cases talks about a feeling.

Comment: Grew can mean become, right? It's a linking verb. What I am saying is the fact I didn't ask about "grow to infinitive".

Comment: @Cardinal You asked about "grow + noun" which is not a thing, and since you were talking more or less about the realm of feelings, that is closer to changes in attitude, which is why I jumped to the "+ Inf." construction. Because you can grow pale and/or old, and neither of those are feelings.

Comment: Also, "become" and "reach a conclusion" are _not_ interchangeable. So the meaning that you have been trying to express is not applicable to the "grow + adjective" situation. You cannot "become a feeling".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can say,

> I grew to like him.

which would mean that at first, you didn't like him, but then, gradually, you came to like him.

But you can**not** say "I grew the feeling of liking him". It evokes an artificial picture of you planting a feeling in a pot and watering it and waiting till it grows.

So it's always

> grow + verb in Infinitive form

Other examples would be, "I grew to respect him", "I grew to appreciate his helpfulness", "I grew to be very fond of her friend", etc.

As for your specific sentence, this construction of "grow + to V" doesn't sit well because this construction implies a change in your general attitude, not in an *assessment*.

Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionary [has several examples](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/grow) of it (under the definition of **"to have or form an opinion, attitude, etc., after time passes — followed by to + verb"**):

> — She's grown to like her new job.
>
> — I grew to admire her very much.
>
> — I grew to feel that these problems were not important.
>
> — She grew to hate him for his selfishness.

The third of these sentences seems similar to yours, but in your sentence, you are speaking about an assessment of something specific, not about a *general attitude* to things that you have formed.

Thus Cookie Monster's suggestion of "I have this growing feeling that I haven't been good enough" is indeed a good replacement for what you are saying.

Comment: Alternatively:  "The feeling that I haven't been good enough grew on me."  (Although, at least in my dialect of English (western CanE), it'd be more common to use this in a positive context, not a negative one.)

Comment: @JimMacKenzie My understanding of "it grew on me" is really restricted to situations where "I've come to like it". E. g., "My husband grew a beard, and I didn't like it at first, but then it grew on me." Also, "grew on me" is basically an idiom. A different subject can be used with it, but it cannot be combined with different verbs and/or adjectives. It really stands on its own (is a self-sufficient predicate).

Comment: ... and thus, "The feeling that [...] grew on me" means that you've come to like the feeling itself. **Not** that the feeling grew.